# Issue performing calculations on grouped LINQ query outputting IEnumerable<decimal> and IEnumerable<decimal?> figures

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, type-conversion

Hi all and thanks for reading/answering (if you do):

I'm having some issues when attempting to get the avg of each transaction across multiple currencies. In the code snippets below I've limited it to just Hong Kong Dollars for the sake of simplicity.

I started off with this:

```
var avgYieldPerTran = (from fixYield in Total
                   group fixYield by fixYield.trans_id into set
                   select new { 
                         PnL = set.Select(s => s.p_and_l), 
                         exHK = set.Select(s => s.exchange_rate_hkd), 
                         size = set.Select(s => s.size)
                   }).ToList();

decimal avgYieldPTHKD = 0;

foreach(var test in avgYieldPerTran)
                {
              avgYieldPTHKD += (((test.PnL / test.exHK) / (test.size / test.exHK)) * 100);
                }
```

PnL & exHK are nullable decimals, size is just a decimal.

The above code gives me the following compile issue for test.PnL / test.exHK:

```
Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type <decimal?> and <decimal?>
```

And this issue with test.size / test.exHK:

```
Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type <decimal> and <decimal?>
```

I tried to get around this by converting to decimal in the following way:

```
avgYieldPBHKD += (((Convert.ToDecimal(test.PnL) / Convert.ToDecimal(test.exHK)) / (Convert.ToDecimal(test.size) / Convert.ToDecimal(test.exHK))) * 100);
```

However, this in turn gives me a runtime issue of:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2[AutomatedTesting.transation, System.Nullable'1[System.Decimal]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

I would then like to Round the final product to 2 decimal places, but I'm hopeful that's something I can figure out on my lonesome.

Any and all help in trying to get round my typecast issues for the sake of getting an avg would be GREATLY appreciated.

Kind Regards.

**edit** Changed the question title, as I have a feeling that the fact that the  and  values are `IEnumerable<decimal> and IEnumerable<decimal?>` may be important...

**edit - Answer** Answer as assisted by Pragmateek below:

```
var avgYieldPerTran = (from fixYield in Total
                   group fixYield by fixYield.trans_id into set
                   select new { 
                         PnL = set.Sum(s => s.p_and_l), 
                         exHK = set.Average(s => s.exchange_rate_hkd), 
                         size = set.Sum(s => s.size)
                   }).ToList();

decimal avgYieldPTHKD = 0;

foreach(var test in avgYieldPerTran)
                {
              avgYieldPTHKD += (decimal)(((test.PnL / test.exHK) / (test.size / test.exHK)) * 100);
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `(myNullabe).Value`? Make sure there are no `null` values.

Comment: If this is not a Linq->SQL or EF Linq statement (i.e. its entirely in memory) then I'd step back to using a loop instead of an iterator. I dont have an insight into why you are getting the results you are, but if you are really stuck and have an urgent deadline, just abandon the use of Linq here.

Comment: It's Linq->EF (which I thought I put a tag for, silly me) but it's not from memory, the 'Total' item is a previous LINQ query - or 2 - to whittle down as much of the filtered out stuff as possible before getting to this point without requiring a complex group by with subqueries. Where would I put the myNullage.Value? Against the exHK and PnL objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Select` returns `IEnumerable`s and there is no `/` operator for them.

You may want something like that:

```
var avgYieldPerTran = (from fixYield in Total
               group fixYield by fixYield.trans_id into set
               select new { 
                     PnL = set.Average(s => s.p_and_l), 
                     exHK = set.Average(s => s.exchange_rate_hkd), 
                     size = set.Average(s => s.size)
               }).ToList();
```

Then you'll obtain a list of objects with `scalar properties`, not a list of objects with `collections properties`.

Comment: I used .Sum() for p_and_l & size, and .Average() for exchange_rate; reason for this being that I want the average exchange rate if multiple results come back, but I want the total PnL or Size of transaction.

However, it's now off by about 2000% from my expected answer. May have to re-think my mathematical approach, but I'm marking this as the answer as it solved the issue. Thank you. 

Worth nothing I had to implicitly convert the calculation by putting (decimal) in front of it.